# Implementing themes in Django (Custom templates by users)

Tags: django, django-templates, theming

I want to implement the feature for admins to set custom templates. Like they can place themes or templates in a particular folder relative to the home folder.

Each theme may have a folder and some config or preview for example(optional).

1) First I need to figure out how to set custom templates dir for an app.

2) Then I can probably do listdir and get all the folders and then give the admin an option to select the dir.

3) A setting list to specify additonal template folders by users.

1 is the problem.

**The main question I want answer for is how to set custom template dir which can be modified anytime.**

I found out that askbot (the SO clone) implements this kinda theming where you can place themes in subfolders a folder and the admin can select the folder which he/she wants the templates.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Django. I guess you can do it using jinja templating.
http://jinja.pocoo.org/
Add a common styling to one html page(base.html)
and then extend the base html to whichever pages u want using extends-- check out template inheritance in the above link

Also you can get some cool templates in bootstrap.. checkout their template section. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_templates.asp

Good luck!

Comment: I already know that.

What I need is for multiple template folders and the ability to select among them. Like wordpress themes

Comment: Like askbot does